# Javascript Routing and Creating Urls /post/id

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm using firebase as a backend and have several `posts` in the database. My files look like:

```
index.html
add-post.html
all-posts.html
```

How can I create routes for post-details such as `/posts/id`.

Do I need to use a framework such as Angular for this kind of dynamic routing?

Comment: You can definitely write your own: ui-router (which Daniel recommends) like most similar frameworks is written in JavaScript and uses W3 APIs to access the necessary browser features. But you'll have to do some more legwork yourself before we can help you here on StackOverflow. For example: have a look at how a popular router framework such as ui-router works and see if you can reproduce the parts that you need.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct if you want to use Angular JS UI router, I leave you the link here, the info is clear, hope it helps

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

If you go to the bottom of the page you'll see that it's explained step by step.

Comment: is it possible to route links with just pure html/javascript?